# Reload Div Section Only

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I don't know if what I am trying to do is possible so I will explain the whole scenario and what I am attempting to do that way if there is a better way you bright people can let me know!

Here is the scenario, I have a view and a PartialView.  In the PartialView I have a dropdown list that gets populated via javascript from in the View.  This works fine, in the PartialView I have a `div` that calls a Controller to return results based on a value in the Model passed to it.  What I need are the results to be based on the value from the Model AND the dropdown list.  Here is the code that works just based on the model value and a hardcoded `loc` which is what I want to get from the dropdown.

```
<div id="catalogue-view-action-view-ct" class="async-partial" data-url='@Url.Content("~/Catalogue_Items/ItemsActionViewPartial/")@Model.CatalogueItemID?loc=6&AsyncUpdateID=catalogue-view'>
    @if (noJs)
    {
        <span>
            @{ Html.RenderAction("ItemsActionViewPartial", "Catalogue_Items", new { id = Model.CatalogueItemID, location = 6, AsyncUpdateID = "catalogue-view-action-view-ct" }); }
                </span>
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/assets/images/busy.gif")" /><span> Loading...</span>
    }
</div>
```

This `div` in the PartialView works great, in the View I have been able to set the `data-url` attribute no problem with javascript but the page is already loaded so it doesn't update.  Is there a way to "refresh" or "reload" just a `div` not the whole PartialView?  If I do the whole PartialView I am just back in the same situation with the html being loaded before the javascript sets the `data-url` attribute.  Here is the javascript in the view:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('catalogue-view-action-view-ct');
            url = '~/Catalogue_Items/ItemsActionViewPartial/20144?loc=' + $('#LocationID').val() + '&AsyncUpdateID=catalogue-view-action-view-ct';
            myDiv.setAttribute('data-url', url);
            $('#catalogue-view-action-view-ct').load(url);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
When using a relative path as I do above the `data-url` gets set properly but the `load` path is incorrect because it is appended.  This is what happens:

```
data-url="~/Catalogue_Items/ItemsActionViewPartial/20144?loc=40&AsyncUpdateID=catalogue-view-action-view-ct"
```

This is perfect, exactly what I need, but the path loaded is:

```
http://www.example.com/catalogue-items/20144/myItem~/Catalogue_Items/ItemsActionViewPartial/20144?loc=40&AsyncUpdateID=catalogue-view-action-view-ct
```

The relative path get added to the end of my current location, I can fix this except I need to remove the "/myItem" portion as that is a parameter for the view that I don't want in the url.  When I use an absolute path I get a cross-origin error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You can reload a div using jquery like this `$("#mydiv").load('YourUrl');`

Comment: Please note that [tag:model-view-controller] is intended for questions about the *pattern*; since your question is about the ASP.NET-specific implementation, use [tag:asp.net-mvc] (I've added here for you).

Comment: @Lal I tried that and it doesn't seem to work for me.  I made the change in my original question so show what I did in case I did something wrong.

Comment: @mgrenier, Do you see any errors at console? Did you added jquery library so you can use the syntax proposed by Lal ?

Comment: Check the browser console for errors please..

Comment: Thanks guys I should have checked here in the first place.  OK here is my dilemma using an absolute path I run into cross-origins issues and if I use a relative path I get the wrong path because the View is called via get and there is a parameter on the end of the path.  I will edit my original question to demonstrate what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a few comments I was able to find a solution for my issue!
With using `$('#catalogue-view-action-view-ct').load(url);` there was actually no need to set the data-url.

But in order to have the relative path work properly I needed to surround it with url.content like so:

```
$('#catalogue-view-action-view-ct').load('@Url.Content("~/Catalogue_Items/ItemsActionViewPartial/")@Model.CatalogueItemID?loc=' + $('#LocationID').val() + '&AsyncUpdateID=catalogue-view-action-view-ct');
```

loading this value produced the desired results. Thanks @Lal for leading me in the right direction!